# Limited qubit number available in Aer Statevector simulator

Tags: quantum-state, qasm, qiskit

I tried to run a calculation of 37 qubits with a Statevector simulator on Qiskit. The following is a demo code.

```
from qiskit import QuantumRegister
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, Aer, execute
from qiskit_aer import AerSimulator, StatevectorSimulator
from qiskit.providers.aer.library import save_statevector
from qiskit import execute, transpile
from qiskit.providers.aer import QasmSimulator

import math
import numpy as np
```

```
simulator = Aer.get_backend('aer_simulator')

stateCirc = QuantumCircuit(37)

stateCirc.x(0)
stateCirc.x(11)
stateCirc.x(21)
stateCirc.x(25)

stateCirc.save_statevector(label='v0')

job = execute(stateCirc, simulator)

result =job.result()

data = result.data()

psi0 = data['v0']

np.vdot(psi0, psi0)
```

This program took infinite time in my laptop...

Later on, I ran the following code

```
simulator = Aer.get_backend('aer_simulator')

simulator.configuration().n_qubits
```

to find that my laptop can only deal with 30 qubits.

Does anyone know if there is any way to get the 37-qubit state vector? Could you show some demo code for demonstration?

Thank you!

Comment: Just note that a 37-qubit statevector encoded in **single** precision is 1Tio of RAM (i.e., 1024Gio). Double this number if you perform your computations in double precision. You would need a pretty beefy laptop to perform this simulation.

Comment: Thank you! I would say that is an elephanty laptop... I am now thinking to run the program on a server. However, I am not sure 1) if I need to parallelize the code;  2) if I could run python with the Qiskit package on a server...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your machine does not have the memory needed to generate a 37 qubit statevector. `n_qubits` for `aer_simulator` is set to [MAX_QUBITS_STATEVECTOR](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-aer/blob/ada56a3b6c185ce3cab383e47b89759eb2347080/qiskit_aer/backends/aer_simulator.py#L958) which is set by the [amount of memory your station has](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-aer/blob/ada56a3b6c185ce3cab383e47b89759eb2347080/qiskit_aer/backends/backend_utils.py#L32). To get a 37 qubit statevector you'll need to run this program on more powerful system. There are services on the cloud like GCP, AWS or Azure that you can leverage.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know if one can apply the Qiskit package on a server with big RAM, e.g., 4TB, memory? I am not sure if I need to the parallelize my serial Qiskit code in the implementation, though.

Comment: 4TB won't get you there. `int(log2(4000 * (1024**3) / 16))` is `37`. This program will crash your beefy server because other processes will also be sharing memory with your simulator. A ~10TB machine might do.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I am not clear what does 16 mean here? Double precision or single precision?

Comment: It's double precision.

Comment: Hey @Marxmas, please [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) my answer if it helped you.